# Ubuntu Not Booting RAID Issues

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have a Ubuntu Server that had been running smoothly for a while now, I came home from work and noticed my clocks flashing, so the power must have blinked off at some point during the day.

I then noticed that my server computer was still powered on, great, it must have been a very short outage!

However, when I go to connect to it, I cannot locate the server anywhere on the network. I connect a monitor to it and reboot the computer and this is what I see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uq14tn7a08yc1ai/IMG_20170418_184327.jpg?dl=0

It will then just repeat that series of four lines starting with "Incrementally starting RAID arrays..." over and over again.

Do you know what might be wrong and, more importantly, how to fix it?